# Checking if an array is unimodal

Tags: c, arrays

An array of integers is unimodal, if:

it is strictly increasing in the beginning;
after that it is constant;
after that, it is strictly decreasing.
The first block (increasing) and the last block (decreasing) may be absent. It is allowed that both of this blocks are absent.

For example, the following three arrays are unimodal: [5, 7, 11, 11, 2, 1], [4, 4, 2], [7], but the following three are not unimodal: [5, 5, 6, 6, 1], [1, 2, 1, 2], [4, 5, 5, 6].

Write a C program  that checks if an array is unimodal.
restrictions: The function should run in the order of n.
No more than n-1 comparison operations should be performed between the array elements.

Can I use 3 while loops (not nested) and check 3 parts of the array if part number1 increasing then part number 2 is constant and part3 decreasing?

Comment: Yes, you probably can use three `while` loops.

Comment: 3 while loops and flags?

Comment: The hardest part is probably the n-1 comparisons restriction. I don't see how to do that.

Comment: I would do it in a one-loop and a state machine, there are n-1 comparisons IMHO with a compare of each pair (n with n+1) or (n with n-1).

Comment: As it stands your question is not worth answering - yes you probably can do it in three loops. But if you are expecting a solution to be posted, you will probably be disappointed.  What you should do is attempt a solution an ask specific questions about any problems you encounter.  I would say that three loops however would be over-complicating the issue - @TomKuschel 's comment should be considered.

Comment: @Clifford Three loops without state variables are always simpler than a single loop with state variables. Apart from that I agree.

Comment: Clifford I dont want ANY solution.  just a guidance

Comment: @AndrewM The way you asked your question the answer is simply "yes", which is too short to post. I'm not sure what you're expecting us to do.

Comment: @melpomene ; I beg to differ, but am not about to post an example.  Three loops is _mathematically_ more complex and will be _more code_.  Simpler to understand is not what I was referring to - although that may be true too.

Comment: @AndrewM ; "Guidance" is not what you have asked for.  Post your attempt and guidance may be forthcoming.

Comment: @Clifford Easier to understand means easier to analyze, including mathematically. Three independent loops in a row are not much more complex than a single loop, but mutable variables and conditional execution complicate things a lot.

Comment: @melpomene ; I think it is straying from the subject somewhat, but loops _are_ conditionally executed.  You may be right - I'd want to see the solutions to compare, but that is not what this question is about.  Interesting discussion, but not perhaps relevant - I appreciate that I started it!

Comment: @melpomene : I think the fundamental difference is state held in a variable vs state represented in the control-flow. They can be equivalent in that sense.

Comment: If you subtract d[n-1] from d[n] and compare the signum() with that of the previous iteration it can be done in one loop and a loop body containing three statements.  One loop, no state-machine.  Arguably also you are subtracting the array elements, not comparing them - but strictly subtraction _is_ comparison.

Comment: despite your failure to improve the question, I chose to answer it.  It is always better not to propose a solution and then ask if it is a good one .  Best to leave it open - you might get a better solution - that is how I chose to answer it.

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible to code this in three loops for each possible stage in the unimodal curve, such a "stateful" algorithm is not particularly mathematical.  Note that an equivalent stateful algorithm is possible in a single loop by  retaining state in a variable rather then in the code control flow.

It is perhaps both mathematically more robust (or at least demonstrates understanding of the mathematics of such a curve), and simpler, to test for a single common-denominator - i.e. a common relationship that holds true for every point on a unimodal curve, but not for any non-unimodal curve.  In that way you can perform the test arithmetically in a single loop rather then by control flow or state transition.

That single common-denominator in this case - one that mathematically defines the curve is this:  *The signum of the gradient of the curve is decreasing-monotonic*.

Signum is a function such that signum(a) is:

- 0 if a == 0,
- 1 if a > 0,
- -1 if a < 0

While *decreasing-monotonic* means the value either falls or remains the same, but never rises - its all down-hill or plateau.

The *gradient* at any point is simply d[n+1] - d[n].  So the loop subtracts one element from the other, determines the signum, and compares it with the previous signum.  The curve is not unimodal if the signum *increases*.   That is it can rise only, be flat only or fall only, or it can rise and fall, but never rise again, with any number of level plateaus.

Note that this solution will work for the mathematical definition of a unimodal curve; the definition in your question is somewhat ambiguous and does not appear to allow for multiple plateaus.  That is to say it allows:

```
   _________
  /         \
 /           \
/             \
```

but excludes for example:

```
      ___
     /   \
 ___/     \____
/              \
```

I think however that the second is clearly unimodal.

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality:
[image]

The last part being key - *zeroes don't count* as a sign change.  Regardless of that subtlety however, it works for all your test cases.